# What is the best way to save credentials in lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-secrets-manager, aws-ssm

I need to access some credentials on lambda functions and one way to do that is to put them in environment variables.

However, the values of these credentials are visible in the lambda console. I am thinking to put them in secret manager or parameter store and put the key as env in lambda. Then load the value in lambda at runtime.

However, this approach is secure but give some latency. I am not sure how much latency it gives. Is there a better solution for that?

Comment: What are the credentials needed for?

Comment: The credentials can be database password, auth2 secrets etc.

Answer (score 2):

The Lambda variables are actually [encrypted](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html#configuration-envvars-encryption) already, the decrypted values are shown from the console but if the user does not have permission for the key they will not be able to see them.

As you suggested you have the solutions of:

- [Secrets Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/)
- [Systems Manager Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html) (use a [SecureString](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-paramstore-securestring.html)).

The benefits that you will get by using either of these solutions is that you can change them outside of the [version](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-versions.html) you're using as well as across a number of Lambda functions simultaneously.

You will also have an increased latency from trying to reach these service endpoints which would lead to a slight increase in time. You could reduce this latency by having your [Lambda within a VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html) and use [VPC endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html) to the service (which will allow direct private communication over using the public internet) but it will still be longer than environment variables.

Ultimately this choice is for you, if you do need to reuse the variables and can put up with the slight latency then use secrets manager or systems manager parameter store. Otherwise manage the [KMS permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/kms-api-permissions-reference.html) so that not every user can access the get to decrypt.

Comment: I'd recommend using Secrets Manager or SecureString in parameter store.

One way to get around the increased latency from the call to these services is to make the call from the 'root' of your function, so outside your Lambda handler - this way the call is only made when the lambda instance is created, and you can store it as a variable for subsequent invocations.This way you only get the latency 'hit' on the first invocation (depends how often the Lambda is invoked as to how effective this is)

Comment: If I made the call from the `root`, will the saved variable available for the next lambda call? I thought lambda is stateless and it doesn't share memory.

Comment: For `the user does not have permission for the key`, how can I create a policy to stop the user reading the key? Does the `key` here mean the environment variables?

Comment: This is for the KMS key that your Lambda uses for every environment variable, more information available here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-environment-variables-iam-access/

Comment: > If I made the call from the root, will the saved variable available for the next lambda call?

Yes, Lambda only initializes the function "context" on cold start. The values you create initialize outside of the handler will be there for the next call. Typically you would also initialize any clients or DB connections there too so if, for example, this secret is used for DB access, you would read the secret, initialize the DB connection, and save the DB connection in the context but not the secret.

Comment: You can do this yes, but plan your credential changes well :)